# Bad quality of Android CameraX preview (viewfinder)

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, preview, android-camerax

I have a problem with a preview using CameraX sample app. Quality of the preinstalled camera app's preview is better then CameraX sample's preview, **but** photos quality is ok. In the sample project touch to focus is implemented too, so it isn't problem, I think. 
I'm using this code to setup a preview use case. What is maybe wrong?

```
private fun buildPreviewUseCase(): Preview {
    val display = viewFinder.display
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { display.getMetrics(it) }
    val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(display.rotation)
            .setTargetResolution(Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
            .build()
            .apply {
                previewSurfaceProvider = viewFinder.previewSurfaceProvider
            }
    preview.previewSurfaceProvider = viewFinder.previewSurfaceProvider
    return preview
}
```

> CameraX sample's preview

[image]

> preinstalled camera app's preview

[image]

Comment: Faced the same issue :( 
And haven't find the solution yet

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue, but after compile and run camerax example app

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXBasic

seems there quality is ok.
I checked difference, and...

somehow, if imageCapture UseCase is not set, quality is bad..
so, try to add

```
val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
    .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
    .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
    .setTargetRotation(rotation)
    .build()
```

and set it into camera

```
camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer
)
```